# Can not post on facebook wall with facebook ios sdk when Application does not run in background has set to YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

i m developing an iPhone application. In my app there is a part to post a news link on user's facebook wall. There is no problem when i set to Application does not run in background property to NO on app plist file. But i dont want to run in background.

Is there anyone has met with this situation before or can give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)? If you do what you can do (a little bit of a hack) is go in `Facebook.m` file and search for a line that says `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];` and change that to `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];`. That will tell the SDK not to use different application to authorize your Facebook App so your app will never quit.